# Getting ORA-00054 error in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00054

I'm getting this error when trying to DROP a table.

I've googled and googled and tried all possible solutions to the best of my abilities but none of them have worked for me so far.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DROP TABLE INTEREST
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified
00054. 00000 -  "resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified"
*Cause:    Resource interested is busy.
*Action:   Retry if necessary.
```

Keep in mind I'm not that knowledgable about SQLDeveloper or SQL itself so please try and be as elaborate as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Some other session is using the table you're trying to drop.  You can keep retrying an eventually you might get a lock.  You may need to ask the DBA to kill whatever session(s) are using the table (and to prevent them from coming back before you're done).  Or you might want to question why you're dropping an object that other people apparently depend on.

Comment: @JustinCave I'm the only person using said table. I've created a table and part of my assignment is to develop queries based around the table. Everything was well until all of a sudden my queries were displaying empty columns so I tried to drop the tables and re-create them altogether but now I'm getting this error.

Comment: Do you have multiple sessions connected to the database?  I'll guess that one of your other sessions is still using the table.

Comment: @JustinCave I've only got one active connection in SQLDeveloper atm. I've tried disconnecting and re-connecting multiple times.

Comment: @JustinCave NEVERMIND I MANAGED TO FIX IT. I was thinking about the connection and you calling it a 'session' got me thinking what you meant. I saw that I had multiple tabs open so I decided to close all of them but the one I was currently using and it works now. Major rookie mistake on my part. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

> ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified

The error is clear that there is a session which manipulated the table, i.e. a **DML** statement was executed, however, there was no **COMMIT** or **ROLLBACK** issued. And, you are trying to **DROP** the table from **another session**.

Note that, when you open **multiple tabs**, i.e. when you **Open multiple SQL worksheets**, there are **different sessions**.

A small demo to reproduce and fix your issue:

**SESSION# 1**

```
SQL> create table t(a number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t select 1 from dual;

1 row created.

SQL>
```

So, I did an INSERT in SESSION# 1 and have not commit it yet.

**SESSION# 2**

```
SQL> drop table t purge;
drop table t purge
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired


SQL>
```

So, when I tried to drop the table in session 2, I get the error.

To fix it, either COMMIT or ROLLBACK session# 1.

**SESSION# 1**

```
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

**SESSION# 2**

```
SQL> drop table t purge;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

Comment: What if I still get the error even when I commit or rollback in session1?. Infact , I am getting the error even If I close all the sessions and open a new session and try to drop the table.  Is something locked? How to get away in this kind of situation.

Comment: Find the session which is causing this using `v$lock` and then find those objects. See http://www.oraclerecipes.com/monitoring/find-blocking-sessions/